# UseEffect returns an error on render when navigating to a page

Tags: react-native, use-effect

My useEffeect on react-native returns an error `{"line":26991,"column":16,"sourceURL":"http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false"}` and I dont know the reason why.

This is my useEffect code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`URL`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(async (data) => {
      try {
        data = Object.entries(data)
        if (data.length > 0) {
          setState(data);
        } else {
          // console.log(data);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('no data');
      }
    }).catch((e) =>{
      console.log("ERROR? " + JSON.stringify(e)) // ERROR HERE.
    });
    console.log("DID YOU RUN??");
  },[]);
```

The error is on the second catch. If I remove the empty array, useEffect will always run. Please help.

Note. While the page is open, if I ctrl+s on my jsfile, the api will run once.

Note: I got it. The problem was ID was assigned but useEffect must not have picked up the ID right away (Don't know the reason). so I added the ID inside the array bracket so that useEffect will rerender when ID is assigned.

the code structure was:

```
const id = props.id;
useEffect ...
```

Comment: Use debugger. The information is not sufficient to guide.

Comment: Why is the second `.then` async? Why are you mixing `try .. catch` with `.then .. .catch`? What exactly is the error? The information you've provided is not sufficient to help you.

Comment: Sorry. I myself am new to react native and this code was left behind by the previous programmer. I will try to explain. after i get the data, I want to pass it to a setstate to be used later in my render. I also tried to remove the try catch inside the data but still getting the same error.